# Making a button within a dedicated buffer

Tags: buttons

Haw can one introduce a button within a dedicated buffer?  With a text area in the middle.

Comment: `C-h i g(elisp)RET m Making buttons`.

Comment: In my opinion, there is nothing simple about creating buttons and forms in Emacs.  What helped launch me in the right direction was playing around with this library: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/widget-demo.el  After you get that semi-working, go ahead and add the tree-mode to the mix which the demo looks for to see if its available.

Comment: There are probably multiple questions here. Can you talk more about what you mean by "dedicated buffer"? Inserting a button is a completely separate question from buffer management.

Comment: The button is introduced in a named buffer make by a package, so that buttons are directed to that named buffer, rather than inserted to the current buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Your elisp code can switch to the buffer, then insert the button.

```
(let* ((buffer-name "my-buffer-name")
       (window (get-buffer-window buffer-name)))
  (if window
      (select-window window)
    (switch-to-buffer buffer-name))
  (insert-text-button "ohmy"
                      'action (lambda (button) (message "clicked the button!"))))
```

Note that depending what else is going on, you might have to delete text in that buffer before inserting the button.